# using groovy script to parse dynamic length array in nifi

Tags: arrays, groovy, apache-nifi

I'm trying to achieve the followings:

Source data (e.g. csv file) contains a string that is semi-colon delimited dates and rates

```
.....,2021-10-10;2021-10-11;2022-01-25,1;2;3,......
```

My schema looks like:
resetRates is an array of record, each record contains a date and rate fields.

Now I'm trying to use groovy script to parse it, since each row of data may contain arbitrary number of date/rate pair (in each row, we guarantee the number of dates and the number of rates match each other).

If I define in groovy:

```
resetRates:[
    [
       resetDate:
       resetRate:
    ]
]
```

How can I get the size of days/rates in each line and create various length of array for each row of data.

If I do:

```
def ratelist = [];
for ( int i = 1; i < rRates.size(); i++) {
   r = [
      "resetDate": getLocalDateTime(rDates[i], "yyyy-MM-dd").toDate(), 
      "resetRate": getDouble(rRates[i])
   ]
   ratelist.add(r); 
}
"resetRates": [
   ratelist    
]
```

Error:

"exception":{"errorCategory":"Severity1","errorType":"SchemaPostValidationFailed","errorText":"Post-validation failed: [

```
{resetDate=Wed Feb 01 00:00:00 EST 2023, resetRate=1.2}
, {resetDate=Fri Feb 10 00:00:00 EST 2023, resetRate=3.2}] is not a valid value for ......: Value is of type java.util.ArrayList but was expected to be of type RECORD}
```

If I do

```
resetRates:[
    getResetRates();
]
```

and make getResetRates turn an array of records, it does not work either.

Comment: There's no question. It's not clear what is the expected result. What is giving an error? Definitely it's not a groovy error...

Comment: I'm not a nifi expert, but could it be that outer array you defined in your schema is assumed or provided by the fact that your code will be called multiple times per line in the CSV and the framework is do that?  It just so happens that your CSV is a single line.  Therefore, you've wrapped your record in an extra level of array?  What if your rateList is just returned?

Comment: @chubbsondubs  I suspect the same will test it out later using 
resetRates: getResetRates(); //without the square brackets. and getResetRates returns an array

Answer (score 0):

Just do
resetRates:getResetRates();

And getResetRates will parse the source data and construct the array of records.
[
getResetRates()
] will construct an array (single element) of array of records which will fail the schema validation.